# Class 'PhpMimeMailParser\Parser' not found

Tags: php

I'm using [this class](https://github.com/optimumweb/php-email-reader-parser) to parse emails.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
ini_set("include_path", '/home/cffcdbfd/public_html/PEAR:' . ini_get("include_path") );

require_once ('classes/email_parser.php');

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$raw = "";
while ( !feof($fd) ) {
    $raw .= fread($fd, 1024);
    $dog = "hi";
}
fclose($fd);

$email = new Email_Parser($dog);
?>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PhpMimeMailParser\Parser' not found in
>   /home/cffcdbfd/public_html/classes/email_parser.php on line 33

The line in question is this:

```
$parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser;
```

The complete email_parser.php code is [here](https://github.com/optimumweb/php-email-reader-parser/blob/master/email_parser.php), though the line numbers are out of whack.

I can see that I have nothing that imports `PhpMimeMailParser` but I can't see where it should come from.

In [composer.json](https://github.com/optimumweb/php-email-reader-parser/blob/master/composer.json) in the original class there's a line to require "php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser" which I'm guessing is [this](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) but I can't see how I can do that myself.

I don't have SSH access so no Composer. All I've uploaded is `email_parser.php`.

Comment: @FlashThunder it's in `email_parser.php` which you can view here: https://github.com/optimumweb/php-email-reader-parser/blob/master/email_parser.php

Answer (score 1):

The class you are looking for is in this project:

https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser

in `src/Parser.php`.

User wrote that he learned on that, so he probably copy pasted some code that requires original class. That doesn't feel good about the project you are using.

Comment: Is there a way I can require the whole of PHP Mime Mail Parser?

Comment: should work, as the second praser has its own namespace... just try to require both?

Comment: So upload PHP Mime Mail Parser to my serve and do `require_once('classes/php-mime-mail-parser')`?

Comment: that seems to be some more complex task, as that class needs this extension: `http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php` ... please read documentation of the project on how to use it properly.